# How to get a specific number of rows from database using JDO?

Tags: java, mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I want to get 10 rows starting from row 20. Is there any way that I can accomplish this using Data Nucleus JDO? I am using MySql as backend.

Comment: Mysql does not have a concept of row number and 10 rows starting from 20 needs to do some ordering preferably with primary key and then use limit offset, something as `select * from table order by primary_key limit 20,10`

Answer (score 1):

As you would find in ANY JDO documentation, something like this would do it

```
SELECT FROM mydomain.MyClass ORDER BY this.id RANGE 20,30
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.. for answering.. I got the answer.. In Jdo query object there is something called
`query.setRange(Start,end)`

Comment: In fact that is what my answer tells you ... just that I use the single-string form of the query. The way to do it on Stackoverflow is you accept the answer that is correct rather than add your own answer.